# Subdomain routing laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

I am trying to run 3 domains with my laravel project one maindomain lets call it mydomain.com de.mydomain.com en.mydomain.com

My route.php is:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'mydomain.com'), function()
{

    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::get('test', 'TestController@index');
    Route::get('collecties', 'CollectiesController@index');
    Route::get('contact', 'ContactController@index');
    Route::post('contact', 'ContactController@postIndex');
});

Route::group(array('domain' => 'de.mydomain.com'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::get('test', 'TestController@index');
    Route::get('collecties', 'CollectiesController@index');
    Route::get('contact', 'ContactController@index');
    Route::post('contact', 'ContactController@postIndex');
});
```

everything on mydomain.com works fine but the problem is: when i go to de.mydomain.com the url changes to de.mydomain.com/de  **notice the /de added add the end** and i get a error 500 Internal Server Error

Did i configurate the route wrong?

**edit**
if i go to de.mydomain.com/test it wont load TestController@index.  if i dont add a parameter (test or something ) so just de.mydomain.com my url says de.mydomain.com/de

my .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.php$">

AddHandler x-httpd-php54 .php

</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I think I would add the apache tag to this question as I don't think the issue is laravel routes.

it sounds to me like your apache config is causing the issue but admittedly i'm not very good with apache.

Comment: Oke thank you i will search that way, but can you confirm my routes.php is oke?

Comment: I can't confirm 100% as I don't have access to my test env at the moment, I've looked at http://laravel.com/docs/routing#sub-domain-routing  not sure if you need to pass in the account like the example shows, have you tried that?

Comment: i have tried that, but it does not work.